# British Visa & Passport

Tags: uk-citizens

I have a EU passport is this still valid in Britain? Also will a British Visa let me back into Australia? Also I THINK my passport is valid until June 2027, how would I make sure?

Comment: By EU passport, do you mean a passport issued by a member state of the European Union?  Or are you referring to a passport that was issued by the United Kingdom but says "European Union" on it because it was issued when the UK was a member state of the European Union?  If you mean the latter, then what do you mean by "British visa"?  Britain does not issue visas to British citizens.

Comment: I mean the second part issued by the UK. I live in Australia as a permanent resident and there is no visa inside, which means I don't know if I could get back home. How do I get a visa through Australian chanels?

Comment: Do you have any document showing that you're a permanent resident of Australia?  Most countries issue a PR card, which you would use in combination with your passport to return to your place of residence from abroad.  But it seems that Australia handles this somewhat differently: https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/permanent-resident/overseas-travel -- are you in Australia trying to figure out how to visit the UK and return, or in the UK trying to figure out how to get home to Australia, or something else?

Answer (score 9):

> I have a EU passport is this still valid in Britain?

Of course.  Britain recognizes passports of pretty much every country in the world.

If you mean that you have a UK passport that says "European Union" on it, then yes, that too remains valid.

> Also will a British Visa let me back into Australia?

No.  You need an Australian visa to enter Australia.

> Also I THINK my passport is valid until June 2027, how would I make sure?

Look at your passport.  The expiration date is on the same page as your picture, name, and date of birth.